# Number of real solution of $e^{4x}+8e^{3x}+13e^{2x}-8e^x+1=0$

Tags: calculus

> Number of real solution of
> $e^{4x}+8e^{3x}+13e^{2x}-8e^x+1=0$

What I try

Using Aithmetu geometric Inequality

$\displaystyle e^{4x}+8e^{3x}+13e^{2x}+1\geq 4(104e^{9x})^{\frac{1}{4}}>8e^x$

So $e^{4x}+8e^{3x}+13e^{2x}-8e^x+1>0$ for all real $x$

But answer given as $2$ real solution

Plz have a look on my problem and what's wrong in this solution

Comment: Why not ask $X=e^x$?https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%5E4%2B8x%5E3%2B13x%5E2-8x%2B1

Comment: See also [this discussion of attacking symmetric quartic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852114/how-to-solve-a-polynomial-with-degree-4/4852162?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C12.7681#4852162).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Set $z=e^x$. This gives

$$z^4+8z^3+13z^2-8z+1 \, = \, \left(z^2 + 3 z - 1\right) \left(z^2 + 5 z - 1\right) \, =\, 0$$

Each quadratic corresponds to two zeroes, for a total of four $z$ values. Finally, you can take their natural log, to find the four corresponding $x$ values. [All four $z$ values](https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28z%5E2%2B3z-1%29%28z%5E2%2B5z-1%29%3D0) are real, and the two positive ones correspond to real $x$ values.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your answer here :

> $$4(104e^{9x})^{\dfrac{1}{4}}> 8e^x$$

put $ x=-4$
$$4(104e^{9x})^{\dfrac{1}{4}}= 4(104e^{-36})^{\dfrac{1}{4}}=0.001576... $$

$$8e^x=8e^{-4}=0.1465..$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=e^x$ so we have

$u^4+8u^3+13u^2-8u+1=0$

$(u^2+3u-1)(u^2+5u-1)=0$

Applying the quadratic formula to each factor we get

$u=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $u=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{29}}{2}$

Since $u=e^x$,we eliminate the negative values and are left with two possibilities.

$e^x=\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2} $ and $e^x=\frac{-5+\sqrt{29}}{2}$.

You can solve for $x$ if you like but this is sufficient to show you will have two real solutions.